# Calling method after for loop is finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have a simple `for loop` that adds objects to an `NSMutableArray` what I need to utilize in a method after the loop finished. I would like to know that how can I detect when the `for loop` is "ready"? Or the `[map addAnnotations:self.nameList];` won't get called until the loop is running so I don't need to care about it?

```
    if (objects) {

        for (PFObject *obj in objects) 
        {

            [self.nameList addObject:obj[@"name"]];

        }

           [map addAnnotations:self.nameList];

     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the executions are sequential in nature, therefore the for loop will be completed first, then the `[map addAnnotations: self.nameList];` method will be called.

So you don't need to care about it.